# EF 6 Inserting entity with provided ID still generates ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity with ID field

```
public class AgentOrder : BaseEntity
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class AgentOrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AgentOrder>
{
    public AgentOrderMap()
    {
        ToTable("AgentOrder");
        HasKey(m => m.Id);
        Property(m => m.Status);
    }
}
```

I create a new entity and define Id property as well. But when I save changes the new entity is created not with Id I've defined but with automatically generated one.

Is it normal behavior of key property?

Comment: Firstly, what is `BaseEntity` and secondly, how are you adding the entity?

Comment: Id column in database is configured to be Identity column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Fluent Configurations, you just need to turn off the default identity insert configuration:

So this:

```
 public AgentOrderMap()
{
    ToTable("AgentOrder");
    HasKey(m => m.Id);
    Property(m => m.Status);
}
```

Becomes:

```
public AgentOrderMap()
{
    ToTable("AgentOrder");
    HasKey(m => m.Id);
    Property(m => m.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    Property(m => m.Status);
}
```

Note that your database needs to support this functionality and have identity inserts turned off as well.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Thank you. However MS SQL required to explicitly allow entering ID field so I decided to leave ID field autogenerated and add one more field for manual adding.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, the id property uses Identity, so, it cannot be manually inserted. Configure it like this:

`Property(l => l.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);`